# Java: How to fix ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

```
public class TextFileExtractor{
    public static String[] fileExtractor(String[] s){

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

            for(int i=0;i<=s.length;i++){
                if(s[i].endsWith(".txt")){
                    sb.append(s[i]);
                    sb.append(',');
                }
            }
        String str=sb.toString();
        String[] sa=str.split(",");

        return sa;
    }
}

import java.util.*;

class P8Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter String Array:");
        String[] data=new String[(scn.nextLine()).length()];
        data=(scn.nextLine()).split(",");

            System.out.print("all Files");
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(data));
                    System.out.print("Text Files");

        String[] res=TextFileExtractor.fileExtractor(data);
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(res));
    }
}
```

Comment: Nail these two as PostIt notes to your forehead `for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )` or `for ( i = 1; i <= n; i++ )`. Anything else is a **smell**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are out of array because in for you use `i<=s.length` but max index of array is `s.length-1`

But I am interested in this

```
String[] data = new String[(scn.nextLine()).length()];
data = (scn.nextLine()).split(",");
```

Why are you creating empty array and then replace it with new one?
I think you wanted to create something more like this

```
String[] data = scn.nextLine().split(",");
```

Earlier you ware creating array based on second line of user input because you ware invoking `scn.nextLine()` twice.

Comment: ya thanx ......but in P8Test class why am i not able to store (scn.nextLine()).split(",") in String[] object data.coz System.out.print(Arrays.toString(data)); is not printing anything when i give dynamic inputs like abc.txt,bbc.txt,bbc.pdf.

Comment: OP is not creating an empty array, but an array with as many members as there are chars in the `nextLine()` string. Not that it matters any :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes you are right. I was editing my post earlier to type something like this but after his second question I resigned :)

Comment: I can see your point fairly clearly, yes :)

Answer (score 9):

With this kind of loop declaration

```
for(int i=0;i<=s.length;i++)
```

you will try to access a total of `s.length+1` array elements, so obviously one of them is out of bounds. Which one, I leave to you (as it is homework).

(or should I have said, to the other fine people on SO? :)

Comment: my fault, +1 for your initiative

Answer (score 2):

The last element will be `s.length`, which doesn't exist, throwing the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

You could use the following approach:

```
    for (String i : s) {
        if (i.endsWith(".txt") {
             ...
        }
    }
```

This is a bit easier to understand (iterates `s` and for each iteration the element of `s` being iterated is accessible over `i`).

Comment: thanx.........but in P8test class why i m not able to store (scn.nextLine()).split(",") in String[] object in data.

Comment: take a look into this line: `String[] data = new String[(scn.nextLine()).length()];` and this line `data = (scn.nextLine()).split(",");` do you see something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here: `for(int i=0;i<=s.length;i++)`
In java, arrays are **0 indexed** so an array starts at `0` and ends at `Length-1`.