# in P8Test class why am i not able to store (scn.nextLine()).split(",") in String[] object data

Tags: java

```
public class TextFileExtractor{
    public static String[] fileExtractor(String[] s){

        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

        for(int i=0;i<=s.length-1;i++){
            if(s[i].endsWith(".txt")){
                sb.append(s[i]);
                sb.append(',');
            }
        }
        String str=sb.toString();
        String[] sa=str.split(",");

    return sa;
}
}


//P8Test.java

import java.util.*;

class P8Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter String Array:");
        String[] data=(scn.nextLine()).split(",");
```

/*Here we are storing the array which we got after converting String (which we read Dynamically) use .split() method*/

```
            System.out.print("all Files");
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(data));
                    System.out.print("Text Files");

        String[] res=TextFileExtractor.fileExtractor(data);
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(res));


    }
}
```

//in P8Test class why am i not able to store (`scn.nextLine()).split(",")` in `String[]` object data.bcoz `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(data));` is not printing anything when i give dynamic inputs like `abc.txt,bbc.txt,bbc.pdf.`

Comment: Maybe this would be interesting for you: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277008/java-how-to-fix-arrayindexoutofboundsexception/11277086#11277086) change

```
String[] data = new String[(scn.nextLine()).length()];
data = (scn.nextLine()).split(",");
```

to

```
String[] data = scn.nextLine().split(",");
```

and then try your code.

Earlier you ware creating array based on second line of user input because you ware invoking `scn.nextLine()` two times.